# Is it possible to disable password

Tags: security

Is it possible to bypass password forever I grow tired of entering it all the time.

I would like to set up the computer so that my parents do not need to enter a password upon wake up and when installing programs.   They are 80 and the more passwords and password reminders I can eliminate the better off we all are.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to go into *System Settings* and  *User Accounts* and set their account to log in automatically. Then go into *Security & Privacy* and *uncheck* "Lock on Sleep" and "Lock after screen shuts down."

As far as using the interface is concerned, they shouldn't have to input a password at all.

To make it even safer for the end user, you can set up their account as a "Standard" (i.e. non-administrator) account, after which you can use the Parental Control settings to limit their access to different programs.

But this is all basic system-admin stuff.  Suffice to say, you should set them up with their own "Standard" account and set that account to log in automatically and the screens not to lock.  If you, as the system administrator, ever need to get in and do things all you have to do is log out of their account and back in as your own.

This won't allow them to do their own system administration, but I suspect you don't want that anyway.